# Data Extract activity for SMS Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, tracking-extract

Newbie alert. There are no options in the Automation Studio to track SMS sends. Data Extract activity at least does not have that option. Is it possible to collect that data through an Sql activity and then export to a file on FTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right RE: Tracking SMS sends automation Studio. Generally reporting is on SMS is not as comprehensive as emails in SFMC (mainly undelivered and no deeper engagement data).

It is possible to query achieve some reporting through queries.

Follow these steps:

1. Write Queries to pick up the data you need from [_SubscriberSMS](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribersms/) and [__UndeliverableSms](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_undeliverable_sms/) data view.
2. Use [Data Extract Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/) to extract the data
3. A [File transfer activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_file_transfer_activity/) to drop it in the Export folder of your FTP.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to get SMS sends info via Job? Or is job only limited to Email sends?

Comment: As far as I understand, _Job is for emails only. http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_job/

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me try it out and come back if your guide worked. I'll accept it as answer if it did.